# Unable to add image path with laravel-manager

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, file-manager

I had difficulty saving the path to my project. My project integrates laravel-manager.
[Select image from laravel-manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92W60.png)
When I confirmed the selection of the image in laravel-manager, no path appeared in the input field.
[Confirm Additional Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZkN9.png)
For additional context, my project does not yet handle user permissions or logins, so I call laravel-manager in web.php as follows:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => []], function () {
    \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
});
```

In config/filesystems, I have configured it as follows:

```
'public' => [
'driver' => 'local',
'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
// 'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
'url' => '/storage',
'visibility' => 'public',
'throw' => false,
],
```

Because when I set the url to env('APP_URL').'/storage', the image paths were incorrect and I could not see them in laravel-manager.
In the file section(create.blade) I use the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="thumbnail" class="form-label">Image<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
     <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <button type="button" id="lfm" data-input="thumbnail" data-preview="holder" class="btn btn-alt-primary">Choose</button>
       </div>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thumbnail" name="ration_image" required>
       @error('ration_image')
          <p class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
       @enderror
     </div>
      <img id="holder" style="margin-top:15px;max-height:100px;" src="{{ old('ration_image') }}" alt="Selected Image">
</div>
```

.....
And use the following script:

```
<script src="/vendor/laravel-filemanager/js/stand-alone-button.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/plugins/jquery-ui-1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
        var route_prefix = "/laravel-filemanager?editor=file";
        $('#lfm').filemanager('image', {
            prefix: route_prefix,
            onSuccess: function(data) {
                $('#thumbnail').val(data.url);
            }
        });
</script>
```

I'm not sure if it doesn't work because I haven't implemented user authentication yet. I'm hoping we can find an answer.

I tried and added in config/lfm.php, I added the following:

```
dir' => 'public/uploads/images', 
'url_prefix' =>' storage/uploads/images',
```

and edited'should_create_thumbnails' => false,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prefix` you use in your filemanager initialization command includes the `editor` parameter, so the filemanager thinks you're using it with a Wysiwyg Editor rather than a standalone button.

Remove the word `editor` from the `prefix`.

For more details, you can ref in [here](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/blob/c31fe60fb37155912d9d93427903919558343c09/public/js/script.js#L778)

Comment: Thank you, I reviewed the laravel-manager open source code in more detail and realized that I had misunderstood it, as you pointed out. Thank you again for solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

upload and images spelling in wrong at

```php
'dir' => 'public/uploads/images', 
'url_prefix' =>' storage/uplaads/immages',
```

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I made a mistake when I posted the question. I will edit the question right away because in the code I wrote it exactly as you answered. Thank you for catching my error.